# What does this text mean on the Apocalypse edition cover?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Pre-ordered Dark Souls 3, got the same cover as the one below.

What language is it, and what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's Russian, means "Prohibited for children." <s>I guess you have the Russian release of the game.</s>
Also, as a little side note - in some countries it is actually illegal to sell M-rated games to children, that's why this text is on the cover.

After a check it turned out that the Apocalypse Edition of Dark Souls 3 does use the same cover for all European countries.

Comment: i doubt he live in russia if doesn't understand russian. how would he got russian release ?

Comment: @NamikazeSheena. You can see a watermark where the Russian text is. My guess is the OP found this picture on the internet and was curious about it.

Comment: It could be what Nolonar said or just that Russia has lower prices for games and some retailers use that to buy and resell games. Not sure if it's technically legal, though... A lot of websites like Kinguin and G2A sell RU releases of Steam games at a marginally lower price, which people activate through VPN services. That, however, is a breach in the Steam Terms of Service.

Comment: I am from the Netherlands, I pre-orderd the Apocalypse edition and also got the Russian text on my cover, very strange. I indeed got this picture from the internet, but I have the same one.

Comment: Also got the PS4 version, so as far a I know, no Steam is involved.

Comment: @doenoe Since I'm primarily a PC gamer I cannot confirm whether or not Russian releases of console games are also cheaper (as Steam games are). So I wouldn't quote myself on that. Maybe the release is the same for several European countries (including Russia and the Netherlands), that could be the case, too.

Comment: @DGarvanski Not a problem, was just wondering that the text is, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just FYI: There is only one "European" version Apocalypse Edition, which has several languages on the box. There's no specific country release. That's why you also see three different age restriction logos in the picture. They just didn't bother to produce different boxes for each country, so every country has all languages and logos on it. I bought it in Germany and it has the same cover.